# A bounded sequence in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\langle x_n\rangle $ be a sequence in $X$.

If ( $f(x_n)$ ) is a bounded sequence for any bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$, then ( $x_n$ ) is a bounded sequence in $X$.

I have to prove this fact. I first thought it would be simple, but it turns out to be trickier...

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hints: Use the isometric embedding of $X$ into the bidual $X^{\ast\ast}$ and the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your hint. Then, I see that X doesn't have to be a Banach space. I think it is sufficient for X to be just a normed space.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PhoemueX said: the statement follows from the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) applied to linear maps $\phi_n:X^*\to \mathbb{K}$ that are defined by $\phi_n(f)=f(x_n)$. ($\mathbb{K}$ stands for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.) The principle applies here because $X^*$ is complete even when $X$ isn't.